# NDSolve-Problem (Calculating field lines)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to calculate the field lines of a quite nasty vectorfield. In general the method works fine - except, one of the components of the VF gets 0 - then `NDSolve` complains about

> ```
> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 300 steps reached at the point s == 0.06617737920434953`
> ```

The weird thing is, that the same routine worked fine in *Mathematica* 7, but starts complaining in newer *Mathematica* versions.

The routine I use, is the following:

```
IntegrateFieldLines[{Ex_, Ez_}, {x0_, z0_}, length_] :=
   Module[{Exs, Ezs},
          Exs[s_] := Ex /. {x -> x[s], z -> z[s]};
          Ezs[s_] := Ez /. {x -> x[s], z -> z[s]};
          NDSolveValue[
            {x'[s] Ezs[s] == z'[s] Exs[s],
             x'[s]^2 + z'[s]^2 == 1,
             x[0] == x0,
             z[0] == z0},
            {x, z}, {s, 0, length}]]
```

Thus, I want to solve $E_x(x,z)/E_y(x,z) = dx/dy$, where x and z are paramatrised by $s$.

The Vectorfield I want to compute is quite nasty

$$\vec E(x,y,z)=Re\left(\frac{e^{i (k r - \omega t)}}{r} \left(k \vec n \times (\vec p \times \vec n )+\frac{(1-i k r)}{r ^2}\left(3 \vec n (\vec p \vec n) - \vec p)\right)\right)\right),$$
where $\omega t=\pi$, $k=2 \pi /5, r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

If you want to play around with it, just copy the Mathematica formula below,

```
    Evec[x_, y_, z_] := Re[Exp[I (k r - \[Omega] t)]/
r (k^2 n\[Cross](p\[Cross]n) + (1 - I k r)/
   r^2 (3 n Dot[p, n] - p))] /. {k -> 2 \[Pi]/5, \[Omega] t -> \[Pi], p -> {0, 0, 0.2}, n -> {x, y, z}/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]}
```

And I only want to get the field lines in the xz-plane, therefore I call

```
IntegrateFieldLines[{Evec[x, 0, z][[1]], Evec[x, 0, z][[3]]}, {4, 0}, 10]
```

if I want to calculate the field line starting at (4,0).

Like I said before, it works fine until `NDSolve` reaches `MaxSteps`. In the following picture, one can see the calculated field lines (in red) and a `StreamLinePlot` - but I can't manage to calculate the full field line.

[image]

I have found at, that the point s, where `NDSolve` stops working, is where $E_z(x(s),z(s)) == 0$:

[image]

For solving my problem, I have already tried out a smaller number in `AccuarcyGoal`, as well as a higher number in `MaxSteps`... but neither worked. Maybe one of you has an idea, how I get `NDSolve` to integrate further and why *Mathematica* 7 could do the job, but all newer versions fail.

Greetings, Jürgen

Comment: This doesn't address the Mathematica issues here, but it looks like you're calculating field line diagrams for dipole radiation in the $xz$-plane.  It turns out that these field lines are expressible as the level sets of another function in the $xz$-plane.  See Zangwill's _Modern Electrodynamics_, §20.5.2, & references therein.

Comment: Mathematica seems to do just fine with the field lines of a static dipole, integrating past the points where $E_z = 0$ without any problem.  Can you post your code for the electric field so that potential answerers can toy around with it?  (Also, as an aside:  it's bad practice to use `E` as a variable name, since that's used by Mathematica for the constant $e$.)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the replies. I also tried out the field lines of a static dipole, and it worked fine for me either! But for the field I posted above, the integration wont get beyond a certain parameter s. Thus I thought it is more Mathematica related than Physics related, because I guess I just have to pass another option to NDSolve in order to get the thing working (and also because it already did work in a previous Mathematica version). And as you have suggested, I have also posted the mathematica expression for the field equation above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the output of your original data, you'll notice that you're getting small imaginary parts in your results.  This implies to me that Mathematica is trying to take square roots, which is why it's failing when $E_z$ is going to zero;  and the main culprit, I believe, is your constraint that $x'(s)^2 + z'(s)^2 = 1$.  Let's differentiate that constraint explicitly to eliminate the possibility of square roots:

$$
x''(s) x'(s) + z''(s) z'(s) = 0
$$

This equation implies that $x'(s)^2 + z'(s)^2$ is a constant $C$, but not necessarily 1.  We can add in an initial condition that this constant be 1 to ensure this:
$$
x'(0)^2 + z'(0)^2 = 1
$$

So we rewrite your code as follows:

```
IntegrateFieldLines[{Ex_, Ez_}, {x0_, z0_}, length_] := 
 Module[{Exs, Ezs}, Exs[s_] := Ex /. {x -> x[s], z -> z[s]};
  Ezs[s_] := Ez /. {x -> x[s], z -> z[s]};
  NDSolveValue[{x'[s] Ezs[s] == z'[s] Exs[s], x''[s] x'[s] + z''[s] z'[s] == 0, 
                 x'[0]^2 + z'[0]^2 == 1, x[0] == x0, z[0] == z0},
               {x, z}, {s, 0, length}]]
```

Running through the same procedure, the equations can now be integrated for the full time:

[image]

My guess as to why your original code worked in previous versions of Mathematica but not the present one is that the previous versions defaulted to a method that didn't have this problem with these particular equations, but that the newer versions pick a different method that fails.  This would imply (to me) that there's problem some `Method` option that would allow your original set of equations to be integrated as well.  I played around with a few of them, but I couldn't get any of them to work;  you might dig around in the `NDSolve` documentation if you're interested in getting your original equations to work again.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem indeed! I have quit often encountered situations, where Mathematica was quite picky with squareroots, but I didn't have thought that the parametrization condition would be a problem! Thanks again!